# Openssl DSA sign

Tags: c++, c, cryptography, openssl, dsa

I am trying to sign some data using a DSA certificate. I am saving the certificate in memory (it was generated with the openssl gendsa command).

My function looks like this, and my problem is with `res = EVP_SignFinal`. Here the function returns 0, and sets the signature_len on 0.

```
bool my_dsa_sign(const Certificate& certificate, const char* messageData, size_t messageLength, Signature &outSignature) {
    bool resultOk = false;
    BIO* bio = BIO_new_mem_buf((void*) certificate.getPEMData(), certificate.getSize());
    if(NULL != bio) {
        EVP_PKEY *pkey = NULL;
        if(NULL != (pkey = PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(bio, NULL, NULL, NULL))) {
            unsigned int signature_len;
            EVP_MD_CTX ctx;
            int res = EVP_SignInit(&ctx, EVP_sha512());
            if(1 == res) {
                res = EVP_SignUpdate(&ctx, messageData, messageLength);
                if(1 == res) {
                    unsigned char* s = (unsigned char*)malloc(EVP_PKEY_size(pkey));

                    // problem here
                    res = EVP_SignFinal(&ctx, s, &signature_len, pkey);
                    if(1 == res) {
                        resultOk = true;
                        signature.setData(s, signature_len);
                    }
                }
            }
            EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);
            EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
        }
        BIO_free(bio);
    }
    return resultOk;
}
```

any idea what the problem might be ?
I have checked with the debugger, the value of the certificate is correct, in the form:

```
-----BEGIN DSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIID....
.......
-----END DSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Also the length is correct, matches with that of the file.

Comment: Just for terminology: A *certificate* is a (more or less public) piece of data containing the public key, some describing data and a signature (usually by someone else), while your private key is separate from this (and not contained in the certificate).

Comment: you are right, I will have to refactor that class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing much of OpenSSL, I don't see anywhere that you are using DSA in your code.

```
int res = EVP_SignInit(&ctx, EVP_sha512());
```

The [manual page to `EVP_SignInit`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_SignInit.html) says:

> `EVP_SignInit()` initializes a signing context **ctx** to use the default implementation of digest **type**.

The [manual page to `EVP_sha512`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/evp_sha512) says:

> [...], `EVP_sha512()`, [...] return `EVP_MD` structures for the [...], SHA512 , [...] digest algorithms respectively.
>   **The associated signature algorithm is RSA in each case.**

Highlight by me.
So it looks like you are trying to do an RSA signature with a DSA key, which will not work (or spit out nonsense).

After some browsing through the documentation, I didn't quite find a way to use SHA512 together with DSA, though, even though the documentation now states:

> The link between digests and signing algorithms was fixed in OpenSSL 1.0 and later, so now `EVP_sha1()` can be used
>   with RSA and DSA, there is no need to use `EVP_dss1()` any more.

Comment: You are right, SHA512 cannot be used with DSA, I didn't think the hashing algorithm will be important. 
I changed it to SHA1 and it works. 
Thanks a lot, I spent almost an entire day looking in the wrong direction.

Comment: Also the fact that I use DSA is only important at the end when using EVP_SignUpdate since the EVP_KEY determines if I do DSA or RSA signing. The PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey method handles all formats transparently.